# How to ensure that Firefox has finished writing to PDF using webdriver and window.print()

Tags: selenium-webdriver, pdf, firefox, printing, webdriver

I am attempting to automate use Firefox to render HTML to PDF. I am using Selenium/Webdriver to automate Firefox. It works great for smaller documents, but for larger ones, the PDFs are incompletely written and malformed (will not open for viewing in Acrobat or a Web browser).

After much experimentation, I figured out that if I print to PDF, then wait for the file to exist, then print it again, wait for the file to exist, and finally wait 15 more seconds, it works, but that is not exactly the kind of thing I'd like to rely on in production! It does not work if I only print once, no matter how long I wait afterward, and if I try to use the file after the second print with a shorter wait, that also doesn't work, even though the file size and last modified time stop changing long before that time.

Is there some way to force the PDF file to be flushed and to know for sure that has happened?

Note that I *do* need to use Firefox for this task because Webkit & Blink use incorrect per-character font selection logic when printing (even though they use correct logic for display) and that produces incorrect output that doesn't meet our requirements.

Comment: It would help if you provided a [mcve]. Can you monitor the size of the generated PDF and then wait until the size stops growing after some period? I have no idea if that would work... I've never tried anything like this but it's the first thing I thought of.

Comment: I'll try to put together a minimal reproducible example html file. Monitoring the file to see when it stops growing is the first thing that I tried, but no amount of waiting produces a complete/valid file. Only printing again and then waiting does. Also, waiting for the file to stop changing does not work because the file only becomes valid a little while after both the file size and last modified timestamp have stopped changing. Somehow, the file content is changed after that without affecting its size or modified time again.

Comment: I was able to figure out a way to avoid just waiting an arbitrary amount of time and hoping that's enough. I poll the file by opening it in a `pypdf.PdfReader`. When that works without raising an exception, then the file is good. Of course, I still have to print the file twice for that to ever succeed which is both kludgy and unnecessarily slow.

Comment: I was referring more to an mcve of the code you are using. What happens when you only print the file once and poll it using pdfReader? Seems like that should work.

Comment: @JeffC When I tried that, the file was never valid, no matter how long I waited. Only printing a second time resulted in an eventually valid file.